# HDMI sound sporadically stops working

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi

I have speakers connected to a monitor, which routes the HDMI sound output to them. The setup works, but occasionally the HDMI sound output just stops working for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the state of graphics device. Disabling and re-enabling solves the problem. However, this can be tricky, because sometimes disabling the device in the Device Manager causes  the screen to become disconnected, and the only way to re-enable is after a hard reboot.

Fortunately this can be automated by a script that automatically re-enables the device without user interaction:

1. Figure out the *Instance ID* of your graphics device by running

   ```
   pnputil /enum-devices /class Display
   ```
2. Create a BAT script with the following content:

   ```
   set DEV="PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68F9&SUBSYS_21811462&REV_00\4&183b18bf&0&0008"
   pnputil /disable-device %DEV%
   timeout /t 3
   pnputil /enable-device %DEV%
   pause
   ```

   and replace the string in quotes in `set DEV="..."` with the above *Instance ID*.
3. Run the script as an administrator as needed.